# Laravel timezone - 15 min behind

Tags: timezone, laravel-5

I am using created_at and getting 13:04 time inserted in database.
My current time is 13:19.

I have set timezone in app.php to "Europe/Ljubljana"

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I can't see any reason for that except that the server time is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your server has wrong time (not synced with actual).

If you could ssh to it, enter `date` in console and see if it matches yours or not, cause laravel using server time to enter it to database.

Comment: Suddenly this is working ok. I am using Homestead VM.